# App crashing in android 11 version only in ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, crash, google-play-services, android-11

my app is working fine in all android versions but on devices with android 11 my app crashes I don't know why can any one please help me with this

Comment: Please provide error message

Comment: are you using camera plugin?? or please provide error message

Comment: Android 11 is a bit more restrictive and requires special permission. Might be you're fetching data from a server, but you did not set permission for ionic to access data from that server.